# field ordering with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script with a sed command that I want to run on a csv file to change the order of some fields. This is what I tried:

```
sed -r '{
   s/(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\8,\9,\10,\11,\7/
}' $1
```

The problem comes because I have 11 fields (i.e. two digit number) so when I specify the desired order i.e.

"\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\8,\9,\10,\11,\7/"

10 and 11 are taken as literals and this ruins my attempt. I have tried the obvious alternatives like:

"\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\8,\9,(10),(11),\7/"

or

"\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\8,\9,{10},{11},\7/"

or

"\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\8,\9,\(10),\(11),\7/"

or

"\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\8,\9,\{10},\{11},\7/"

But none of these work, they are also treated as literals. I am running out of imagination, do not know what else to try, any ideas?

I know there are other ways of going about this problem (like `awk` etc), but I would appreciate if your answers are focused in `sed` since the rest of my code is done using `sed`.

Wish to thank you all in advance!

Comment: '()' have to be escaped like this `...\(.*\),\(.*\)...` And personally I'd suggest to use `awk -F, '{print $1, $2, $3...}'` in this case

Comment: @Ivan: please note option `-r`!

Comment: Tools like bash/sed/awk can't manage CSV files that contains text with line breaks. In this case the logical line is split into 2 or more physical lines. Also all solutions here are broken, if a text contains a comma. Use the special functions of e.g. php or python to scan CSV files correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I see three blocks: fields 1-6, field 7 and the rest. So you can use

```
sed -r '{s/^(([^,]*,){6})([^,]*),(.*)/\1\4,\3/}'
```

Answer (score 1):

From `info sed`

> The REPLACEMENT can contain '\N' (N being a number from 1 to 9,
> inclusive) references, which refer to the portion of the match which is
> contained between the Nth '(' and its matching ')'.

So `\10`+ will be taken literally.

`perl` however does not have this limitation

```
$ perl -pe 's/([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )([^ ]* )(.*)/$14 $13$12$11$10$9$8$7$6$5$4$3$2$1/g;' <<< "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen"
fourteen thirteen twelve eleven ten nine eight seven six five four three two one
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of (ab)using sed, I'd do this with `csvcut` from the [csvkit package](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of utilities for working with CSV files:

```bash
csvcut -c 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,7 old.csv > new.csv
```

Or using `perl` instead:

```bash
perl -F, -lane 'print join(",", @F[0..5, 7..10, 6])' old.csv > new.csv
```

(Splits each line into an array on commas, and print out a reordered version; no ugly regular expressions needed.)

Comment: Don't fixate on sed (or regular expressions) when there are better suited, simpler and more readable ways.

Comment: Another tool is [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) which supports ranges: `xsv select 1-6,8-11,7`

Answer (score 0):

There simply isn't a way in `sed` to reference a 10th or later capture; only `\1` through `\9` are recognized.

This sort of thing is more in the wheelhouse of `awk`, so even though you asked for `sed` solutions, I'll offer a couple `awk` solutions as examples.

Since `awk` happily recognizes multiple-digit field numbers, and we don't really have any choice but to treat every occurrence of the field separator as marking a new field anyway, we're counting all the fields separately, unlike @leu's `sed` answer. But that means these solutions lend themselves more easily to modification for more thorough shuffling of the fields.

Here's a straightforward sequence of field assignments with a temp var to remember the first one until we need it:

```
$ awk -v{,O}FS=, '{t=$7;$7=$8;$8=$9;$9=$10;$10=$11;$11=t}1'
```

Although since you have a whole block of fields being shifted left by one position, perhaps a more systematic approach with a loop would be suitable:

```
$ awk -v{,O}FS=, '{t=$7; for (i=7;i<11;++i) { $i=$(i+1) }; $11=t}1'
```

If you were shifting a larger number of items by the same amount, the loop would make more sense; if the rearrangement was more random, the series of direct assignments would make more sense. In this case, they're about the same amount of code, so it's a toss-up.

Comment: Can you please describe what is `-v{,O}FS` ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Many shells (but not POSIX sh) expand `-v{,O}FS=,` to `-vFS=, -vOFS=,`. `-v` is an awk option to set **v**ariables.

Comment: The option `-v name=value` sets a variable in awk, which is a convenient way to pass a value in without the messy quoting issues you run into trying to interpolate it directly into the code. Some variable names are special to awk:  FS and OFS tell awk what strings to use to split input into fields (FS) and join those fields back together for output (OFS).  Since I wanted to set them both to the same thing, and this question is tagged "bash", I used bash brace expansion: `awk -v{,O}FS=,` turns into `awk -vFS=, -vOFS=,`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/,?[^,]*/\n&\n/7;s/\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/' file
```

Delimit the seventh field by newlines and then swap it to be at the end of the line.